# Create a Price Tag Icon with Rounded Corners

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon

I am learning to create icons in Photoshop, but I'm not sure how to tackle creating this icon.

Is it possible using only Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: I think you should make it in Illustrator.

Comment: [Here's why](https://imgur.com/a/HFQfiif) you should make it in Illustrator, not Photoshop.

Comment: If you're learning I think you need to learn when to use raster and vector images and what their consequences are. In this instance, a solid raster image would be a larger file size than a vector and non-scalable without pixelation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is *entirely* possible to create this in Photoshop, using the pen tool to create vector paths, stroking the paths; it would however be far *easier* and ***faster*** to create this as vector art in [**Illustrator**](https://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) or [**Affinity Designer**](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/), [**Sketch App**](https://sketchapp.com/) or [**Inkscape**](https://inkscape.org/).

That said, it's a very basic beziér pen tool exercise - I'd start by drawing it aligned horizontally and rotating once you have it complete to make the process simpler:

I set up guides to make proportioning easier (and I add more as I go through) and start my vertical penline by snapping to the lefthand vertical guide I drew - use `shift` to constrain the lines to 45º increments:
[image]

Complete the basic round-rect shape:
[image]

Switch to the add a point pen tool (has a + symbol by it), and add a point at the centre of the right-hand vertical segment of your path:
[image]

Switch to the **white** arrow (direct select) tool and pull out that just-added anchor point, with `shift` held to constrain to a horizontal movement:
[image]

Add an ellipse to your path for the hole, starting at the centre (I added a guideline) by holding `option` (Mac) or `alt` (Win) as you click and pull; switch to the Paths palette (next to the Layers palette), choose your work path and right-click on it to then choose "**Stroke Path**" (note: select your brush and brush size *first*!):
[image]

And this is the result.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @cipriano, to expand a little why this would be simpler in AI... You can just make a rectangle, add an anchor point to the middle, move it to the right by dragging and then round the corners after the base shape is done. This way you don't have to worry about screwing up the rounded corners. In PS you have to get somewhat tricky. I'd probably make a rectangle + a square with the same border radius and rotate the square 45 degrees to make the triangle at the end. Those can then be merged into a single shape. Though that can only give you a 45 degree angle on the triangle.

Comment: @Joonas totally agree with your comment - far simpler, more efficient, more controllable, more export options from ANY vector art app!